# Straight line equation is linear or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions

I read somewhere that for the linearity the equation should pass through the origin in this regard the equation of straight line y=mx+c is linear or not?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by *linear*: directly proportional or on a straight line.

Comment: Here is how I see it. There is one interpretation on *'linear'* from Linear Algebra where the word linear relates to linear combination therefore in a function is called linear if it preserves the linear combination of the vectors in the argument. Another interpretation is from geometry wherein lines planes, hyper planes always are represented by degree one polynomials. From this you get the concept linear polynomials, linear ODE's PDE's etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different uses of the word *linear*:

1. *Behaving as a polynomial of degree 1*, i.e. $mx+c$, as opposed to *quadratic*, *cubic*, &c.
2. *Satisfies a functional equation*, in particular,
   $$ f(ax+by) = af(x)+bf(y), $$
   for every $x$, $y$, $a$ and $b$ (where $x$ and $y$ might be vectors, for example, but $a$ and $b$ are real or complex numbers [not the most general case, but sufficient]).

The second is a subset of the first for real-valued functions of the type you're asking about: if $f(x)=mx+c$, then
$$ f(ax+by)-af(x)-bf(y) = m(ax+by)+c-a(mx+c)-b(my+c) = (1-a-b)c, $$
which is only zero if $c$ is zero, i.e. the graph of $y=f(x)$ passes through the origin.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing terminology. The equation $$y = mx + c$$ (assuming that $x,y$ are variables and $m,c$ are constants) is a **linear equation** in $x$ and $y$. However, if $c$ is non-zero, then we would say that the line does not represent a **vector space**, as it does not pass through the origin.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation) is some information on linear equations.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) is some information on vector spaces.

Comment: To make it a bit more confusing, "linear space" is sometimes used as an alternate term for "vector space".